# bokeh check if session active

Tags: session, bokeh, session-state

Is it possible in [Bokeh](https://bokeh.org/) to check if session is active? I'm drawing live data streamed from other thread, I want to stop streaming as soon as client closes session (e.g. closes tab).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `on_session_destroyed` lifecycle hook as described in the documentation:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#lifecycle-hooks

Note that destruction of expired sessions is a task that happens *periodically* (at a configurable interval) so the hook will not execute *immediately* at a session disconnect.